# How would you solve this problem with inputs

Tags: javascript, html

We have 4 inputs. We want all 4 to be fully adjustable and have the sum of all always equal the a fix value.

Example we have 4 inputs that max out at 100. We want to sum of all 4 to always equal 100. So that when one slider moves the total above or below 100 another input must automatically change to keep the total at 100 so that if 3 of the inputs were moved to 0 the 4th input would be at 100.

So which one would be tide to witch one and how so that the user can easily achieve the desired input amounts.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [joeneuman.com](http://joeneuman.com/images/problem.png))</sub>

Comment: Voting to close this. If you require help, please show your code attempts, and specific issues you encountered. 
_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._

Comment: One solution would be to have two of the four fields locked at any given moment. Now the only two active fields would be locked to each other. If one goes up the other goes down. I'm not sure if that is necessary or not? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9vWi.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9vWi.jpg)

Comment: I think https://ux.stackexchange.com/ would be better place for this question

Answer (score 1):

The question is *how* you want to distribute the correction value across the other fields: when you raise one value, you can lower just one, or three fields with one third of the needed correction value. This is a matter of taste or requirement, I'd say. Besides that: technically, I'd create one function that gets called from all sliders on change. Depending on the sender, you then conduct the correction changes to the other fields.

Comment: Correct, the question is what is the best way to do this and have it make sense to the user. 

Let's say we want the total to be 100% The first two fields are at 50%. Now you start to move the 3rd field up. Do you have the 2nd field come down, the first or both? What happens if you now go back to field one and move it down, which field now gets moved up? Many unanswered questions.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but that's like asking "what do you think my favorite color should be"? There are multiple ways to do it, and the best way imo can only be determined by getting more information about the actual context and purpose of this UI. If there are no (operational) constraints, I'd probably simply go to the customer/user and ask what he'd like the best.